# How to change <h:commandLink> styling for selected one?

Tags: css, primefaces

I have two commandLink in my code.

```
<h:commandLink  action="#{localeController.switchLocale('en')}" value="English"/> |
<h:commandLink  action="#{localeController.switchLocale('fr')}" rendered="true" value="French"/>
```

I want to set some css styling for the selected Link. I tried with `a:visited` but its not working. How can I make some changes for the selected Link?

Please suggest!

Comment: Have you tried a:active ?

Comment: @erdimeola: Yes, its not working